# Running a 64bit program referencing a 32bit dll using visual studio - C#

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, wrapper

I am currently facing a problem where I am referencing a 32bit dll. I tried changing the platform to 86bit which works fine but the requirements are to use a 64bit or 'Any CPU'. When I use the 'Any CPU' platform it somehow does not pick up the dll

Is there a way of using a 32bit dll in 64bit program?
I also read about a workaround of 'wrapping' which was not clear... can someone elaborate

Comment: It would not be a simple wrapper. You would either need thunking, or you would have two separate processes and use IPC to communicate between them. Not something you are going to be able to do at this skill level. Treat it as a hard requirement that the bitness of a DLL matches the bitness of the application. Ask the person who gave you that 32-bit DLL for a 64-bit version of it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way of using a 32bit dll in 64bit program?

In the same *process*: No.<sup>*</sup>

However, you could host the dll in a separate child process via something like the Add In Framework (which supports out of process workers).

<sup>*</sup> Note, I am assuming this dll is either natively compiled, or .NET but compiled explicitly for 32bit only.